# JavaScript/jQuery - How to detect if a page is embedded by others?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a page `index.html`, how can I detect, using JS or jQuery, if my page is embedded in other HTML page through a `frame` or an `iframe`?

```
+----------------------+
|  Other people's site |
|   +------------+     |
|   | index.html |     |
|   | oops!      |     |
|   | embedded!  |     |
|   +------------+     |
|                      |
+----------------------+
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if(window.top !== window.self) {
    // embedded
}
```

`window.top` is the top-level window. `window.self` is the window the script is executing in. If the current window is not the top-level window, it must be embedded.

Comment: @domanokz: I edited my answer to include a short explanation.